# Got bad array subscript when wring a function printing the fibonacci numbers

Tags: bash, array, function

This is my code to write a function which prints the Fibonacci numbers

```
function fib {
        fib_array=( 0 1 )
        count=3

        while [[ $count -le $1 ]]
        do
                fib_new=$(( ${fib_array[-1]} + ${fib_array[-2]} ))
                fib_array+=( $fib_new )
                let count=$count+1
        done

        echo " ${fib_array[*]}"
}
```

When I run my bash with `fib 5`, I keep getting the messages :

```
-bash: fib_array: bad array subscript
-bash: fib_array: bad array subscript
-bash: +  : syntax error: operand expected (error token is " ")
```

I assume the there might be some problems in the 1st line within the while do, i.e. `fib_new=$(( ${fib_array[-1]} + ${fib_array[-2]} ))` but don't know how to modify.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I could not reproduce it, I get the expected output: `0 1 1 2 3`.

Comment: What is your version of bash? negative array subscripts were introduced in 4.3 if I'm reading the `NEWS` file correctly

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using a version of bash that doesn't understand a negative array like `array[-1]`. You could install a more recent version of bash (above 4.3) or you can try this script:

```
fib () {
          fib_array=( 0 1 ); size=2
          limit=$1

          while [[ size -lt limit ]]
          do
              fib_arr+=( "$(( ${fib_arr[size-1]} + ${fib_arr[size-2]} ))" )
              size=${#fib_arr[@]}
          done

          echo " ${fib_arr[*]}"
}

fib "${1:-10}"
```

which use the size (of the array) variable to avoid negative indexes.

Or, if you want a slightly faster option that works for all bash shells, use:

```
fib () {
         limit=$1
         set -- 0 1
         printf '%s %s' "$1" "$2"; count=3
         while [ "$count" -le "$limit" ]; do
              t33=$(($1+$2))
              set -- "$2" "$t33"
              printf ' %s' "$t33"
              count=$((count+1))
         done
         echo
       }

fib ${1:-10}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to put [count-1] instead if [-1] and [count-2] instead if [-2]

Comment: This has already been covered in another answer.